# Sending GoerliETH to a contract return "out of gas" and "execution reverted"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, metamask

I'm using the Remix IDE to Deploy a Solidity Smart Contract.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract sendMonetSolidity{
    uint public receiveBalance;

    
    function sendMoney()public payable{
        receiveBalance += msg.value;
    }

    function getBalance()public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }


    function withdrawMoney() public {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(this.getBalance());
    }

    function sendMoneyToSpecidicAddress(address payable _to) public{
        _to.transfer(this.getBalance());
    }


    
}
```

Injected Provider was MetaMask, while I sent and withdraw anything was well in the same browser. Then I started to send Goerli from another account, it was fail with an error "out of gas".

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x44433868cc8b2726ca98ebe9bb5339b7a7c8d945

If I increased the gas fee, return error of "execution reverted"

Answer (score 0):

Contracts reject all native token payments (ETH on Ethereum, MATIC on Polygon, ...) by default.

You need to implement either `receive() external payable` or `fallback() external payable` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#special-functions) in order to accept native token payments.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract sendMonetSolidity {
    receive() external payable {
        // can be empty - don't forget to implement separate function for withdrawal
        // or you can redirect the payment to some EOA here
    }

    // ... rest of your code
}
```